# Adding 2 HTMLGenericControl script with src attribute not working

Tags: asp.net, scripting, htmlgenericcontrol

I have asp.net 2.0 c# application.
I have 2 scripts I want to add to a user control's control collection. Instead of adding them one after another, it only opens one script tag and throws the 2 src strings together as strings

```
string tagLinks = "/Resources/Javascript/js/taglinks.js"; 
HtmlGenericControl scriptTagLinks = new HtmlGenericControl("script"); 
scriptTagLinks.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript"; 
scriptTagLinks.Attributes["src"] = tagLinks; 
this.Controls.Add(scriptTagLinks);

script = new HtmlGenericControl("script"); 
script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript"); 
script.Attributes.Add("src", gsJSHost); 
this.Controls.Add(script);
```

This is what happens:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/Resources/Javascript/js/taglinks.jsvar pageTracker =
_gat._getTracker('UA-1213766-27'); pageTracker._initData();pageTracker._trackPageview();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've found out about your answer:

I added (basically) your code to my user control loaded event (which will inject the script tags that you're looking for).  I don't have the global script that is contained in your `gsJSHost` global variable so I substituted with the variable name.

This is my control code:

```
Public Partial Class MyControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim tagLinks As String = "/Resources/Javascript/js/taglinks.js"
        Dim scriptTagLinks As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("script")
        scriptTagLinks.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript")
        scriptTagLinks.Attributes.Add("src", tagLinks)
        Me.Controls.Add(scriptTagLinks)

        Dim script As New HtmlGenericControl("script")
        script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript")
        script.Attributes.Add("src", "gsJSHost")
        Me.Controls.Add(script)

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is my resulting page source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUIMTI2NzczMzlkZE8ExRatvhvKqmX5DtpWJX8MhAcE" />
</div>

    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Resources/Javascript/js/taglinks.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="gsJSHost"></script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please download the source code at my Google code demo project: 
http://code.google.com/p/stackoverflow-answers-by-scott/

Direct link to zipped download:
http://stackoverflow-answers-by-scott.googlecode.com/files/1716701.zip

I hope this helps,

### Thanks!